Excel VBA: Loop through headers and cells of a table not working properly
The following code is a WIP. Everything works, except of the two commented out blocks.

Transferring Header Names
After the first header was transferred from one sheet to another, the loop breaks for some reason.

Getting Cell Names
Always getting the error subscript out of range without even entering the loop once. The test tables have only two rows. The first one has a value, the other one is empty.


Option Explicit

Sub GetCellNames(CatRange As String, ArtRange As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cellNames As Object
    Dim headerArr As Variant
    Dim cellArr As Variant
    Dim tblName As String
    Dim headerRow As String
    Dim selectRow As String
    Dim selectCol As String
    Dim header As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set ws = Worksheets(Range(CatRange).Value)
    tblName = Worksheets(1).Range(ArtRange).Value
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(tblName)
    Set cellNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    selectCol = Chr(Asc(Left(ArtRange, 1)) + 1)
    selectRow = Right(ArtRange, 1)
    headerRow = Chr(Asc(selectRow) - 1)

    'Getting Header Names
    For Each header In tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells
        If Not Right(header.Value, 1) = "2" Then
        
            '1. Transferring Header Names
'            Worksheets(1).Range(selectCol + headerRow).Value = header.Value

            '2. Getting Cell Names
'            For Each cell In tbl.ListColumns(header).DataBodyRange
'                If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then cellNames.Add cell.Value
'            Next cell

            ' Transform to Array
            cellArr = cellNames.ToArray
            ' Create Drop-Down List
            Call List.CreateDropDown(selectCol + selectRow, cellArr)
            
            selectCol = Chr(Asc(selectCol) + 1)
        End If
    Next header

End Sub

I already tried the following but got the same error:
For Each cell In ws.Range(tblName).ListObject.ListColumns.Item(header).Range
For Each cell In ws.Range(tblName + "[" + header + "]")


You're trying to add 2 strings: selectCol + headerRow.


Solved it
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call Spec.GetCellNames(CatRange, ArtRange)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Still not wrking


What line throws the subscript out of range error?

 'Getting Header Names
    For h = 1 To tbl.ListColumns.Count
        header = tbl.ListColumns(1).Range(1, h).Value
        If Not Right(header, 1) = "2" Then
            'Transferring Header Names
            Worksheets(1).Range(selectCol + headerRow).Value = header
            'Getting Cell Names
            Set cellNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
            If Not IsEmpty(cellArr) Then Erase cellArr
            For c = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
                cell = tbl.ListRows(1).Range(c, h).Value
                If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then cellNames.Add cell
            Next c
            ' Transform to Array
            cellArr = cellNames.ToArray
            ' Create Drop-Down List
            Call List.CreateDropDown(selectCol + selectRow, cellArr)
            selectCol = Chr(Asc(selectCol) + 1)
        End If
    Next h

This link helped me to find the solution.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
